# Remove additional spacing in string [Fastest Way]

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I need to remove all additional spaces in a string.
I use regex for matching strings and matched strings i replace with some others.
For better understanding please see examples below:

3 input strings:

```
Hello, how are you?
Hello , how are  you?
Hello     ,     how    are   you    ?
```

This are 3 strings that should match by one pattern-regex.
It looks something like this:

```
Hello\s*,\s+how\s+are\s+you\s*?
```

It works fine but there is a perfomance problem.
If I have a lot of patterns (~20k) and try to execute each pattern it runs very slow (3-5 minutes).

Maybe there is better way for doing this?
for example use some 3d-party libs?

**UPD: Folks, this question is not about how to do this. It's about how to do this with best perfomance. :)**

---

Let me explain more detailed. The main goal is tokenize text. (replace some token with special symbols)

For example I have a token "nice try".
Then I input text "this is nice try".
result: "this is @tokenizedtext@" where @tokenizedtext@ some special symbols. It doesen't matter in this case.

Next I have string "Mike said it was a nice       try".
result should be "Mike said it was a @tokenizedtext@". 
I think the main idea is clear.

So I can have a lot of tokens. When I process it I convert my token from "nice try" to pattern "nice\s+try". and try to replace with this pattern input text.
It works fine. But if in tokens there is more spaces and there is also punctuation then my regexes became bigger and works very slow.

Do you have some suggestions (technical or logic) for solving this problem?

Comment: If you show us the full method we could probably point out the slow points in it, but as it stands youve just given small snippets that alone arent really helpful. For example you could have mistakenly compared each single one of the 20k to each of the others, instead of comparing it to one successful one, which would obviously be much slower!

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4538439/1916110 - it explains in details slow c# regexp

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your expected result?

Comment: @alexi - pls do explain what kind of output you are expecting

Comment: In reply to the Update again, we cant improve your performance if you dont show us your code!

Comment: @RhysW Please see one more update. May be I do something wrong logically. Or I can implement better logic instead constructing from tokens patterns?..

Comment: Youll need to post the code youre currently using to do this. More explanations dont help in this case. we cant improve performance of an explanation, we really do need the actual code you are currently using. How are we meant to know if our solution is more efficient if we dont have yours to run alongside it to test?

Comment: @OP: Are you pre-compiling the regular expression?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have some reasons not to compile regexes.

Comment: @AlexeiMalashkevich - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14318926/922198

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest a few solutions.

First of all, avoid the static `Regex` method. Create an instance of it (and store it, don't call the constructor for each replacement!) and, if possible, use `RegexOptions.Compiled`. It should improve your performance.

Second, you can try to review your pattern. I'll do some profiling, but I'm currently undecisive between:

> @"(?<=\s)\s+"

With replacement being an empty string or:

> @"\s+"

With a space as a replacement. You can try this code, in the meanwhile:

```
var s = "Hello , how are  you?";
var pattern = @"\s+";
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
var replaced = regex.Replace(s, " ");
```

**EDIT**: After having done some measurement, the second pattern seems to be faster. I'm editing my sample to adapt it.

**EDIT 2**: I've written an `unsafe` method. It's much faster than the other ones presented here, including the Regex ones, but, as the word itself says, it's unsafe. I don't think that there's any problem with the code I've written but I may be wrong -- So please, check it again and again in case there's a bug in the method.

```
static unsafe string TrimInternal(string input)
{
    var length = input.Length;
    var array = stackalloc char[length];
    fixed (char* fix = input)
    {
        var ptr = fix;
        var counter = 0;
        var lastWasSpace = false;
        while (*ptr != '\x0')
        {
            //Current char is a space?
            var isSpace = *ptr == ' ';
            //If it's a space but the last one wasn't
            //Or if it's not a space
            if (isSpace && !lastWasSpace || !isSpace)
                //Write into the result array
                array[counter++] = *ptr;
            //The last character (before the next loop) was a space
            lastWasSpace = isSpace;
            //Increase the pointer
            ptr++;
        }
        return new string(array, 0, counter);
    }
}
```

Usage (compile with /unsafe):

```
var s = TrimInternal("Hello    , how       are     you?");
```

Profiling made in Release build, optimizations on, 1000000 iterations:

> My above solution with Regex: 00:00:03.2130121
>
> The unsafe solution: 00:00:00.2063467

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use `Compiled` option. (

Comment: @AlexeiMalashkevich It's a little bit slower without the `Compiled` option but it's still pretty fast. I'll try to make another method.

Comment: @AlexeiMalashkevich I've written a method which should be faster than the others suggested. Please try it.

Comment: Looks interesting. Will test this. For now the best answer.

Comment: sorry for delay. Will test it in week or two.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you. It should be pretty fast. Note that it also removes spaces at the end of the string; that might not be what you want...

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">{0}<", RemoveExtraSpaces("Hello, how are you?"));
            Console.WriteLine(">{0}<", RemoveExtraSpaces("Hello , how are  you?"));
            Console.WriteLine(">{0}<", RemoveExtraSpaces("Hello     ,     how    are   you    ?"));
        }

        public static string RemoveExtraSpaces(string text)
        {
            var buffer = new char[text.Length];
            bool isSpaced = false;
            int n = 0;

            foreach (char c in text)
            {
                if (c == ' ')
                {
                    isSpaced = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (isSpaced)
                    {
                        if ((c != ',') && (c != '?'))
                        {
                            buffer[n++] = ' ';
                        }

                        isSpaced = false;
                    }

                    buffer[n++] = c;
                }
            }

            return new string(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something of my own :

find all the position of WhiteSpacechar in string;

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetWhiteSpacePos(string input)
{

    int iPos = -1;
    while ((iPos = input.IndexOf(" ", iPos + 1, StringComparison.Ordinal)) > -1)
    {
        yield return iPos;
    }
}
```

Remove all whitespace that are in in sequence Returned from **GetWhiteSpacePos**

```
        string original_string = "Hello     ,     how    are   you    ?";

        var poss = GetWhiteSpacePos(original_string).ToList();
        int startPos;
        int endPos;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(original_string);
        for (int i = poss.Count -1; i > 1; i--)
        {
            endPos = poss[i];
            while ((poss[i] == poss[i - 1] + 1) && i  > 1)
            {
                i--;
            }
            startPos = poss[i];
            if (endPos - startPos > 1)
            {
                builder.Remove(startPos, endPos - startPos);
            }

        }

        string new_string = builder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

if its just a matter of SPACE;

try this
Source : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10890/Fastest-C-Case-Insenstive-String-Replace

```
    private static string ReplaceEx(string original,
                string pattern, string replacement)
    {
        int count, position0, position1;
        count = position0 = position1 = 0;
        string upperString = original.ToUpper();
        string upperPattern = pattern.ToUpper();
        int inc = (original.Length / pattern.Length) *
                  (replacement.Length - pattern.Length);
        char[] chars = new char[original.Length + Math.Max(0, inc)];
        while ((position1 = upperString.IndexOf(upperPattern,
                                          position0)) != -1)
        {
            for (int i = position0; i < position1; ++i)
                chars[count++] = original[i];
            for (int i = 0; i < replacement.Length; ++i)
                chars[count++] = replacement[i];
            position0 = position1 + pattern.Length;
        }
        if (position0 == 0) return original;
        for (int i = position0; i < original.Length; ++i)
            chars[count++] = original[i];
        return new string(chars, 0, count);
    }
```

Usage:

```
        string original_string = "Hello     ,     how    are   you    ?";
        while (original_string.Contains("  "))
        {
            original_string = ReplaceEx(original_string, "  ", " ");
        }
```

Replacing the regex way:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"\s+", " ", RegexOption.Compiled);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Your method is inefficient and unreadable. It's about three times slower than a compiler Regex.

Comment: @Eve: I bet you've timed a debug build rather than a release build.

Comment: @MatthewWatson No. The worst problem is the `while` block. It creates a new instance of the string for each couple of spaces found in it.

Comment: Oh right, you mean the code in the usage block, not the implementation of ReplaceEx().

Comment: @MatthewWatson The implementation has problems as well. It calls `ToUpper` twice and it creates two new strings (plus the return one). Furthermore, it creates a `char` array (I haven't tried to read what it actually is for). It's all overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, these kind of problems really trouble us. Use this code, and I'm sure you're getting the result for what you've asked. This command removes any extra white space between any string.

```
cleanString= Regex.Replace(originalString, @"\s", " ");
```

Hope thar works for you. Thanks.

And since this is a single Instruction. It will utilize less CPU resource and hence less CPU time, which ultimately increases your performance. Therefore A/C to me this method works the best when compared in terms of performance.

Comment: there is no need of groups here

Comment: or Instead Only 

    **bold**Regex.Replace(originalString, @"\s+", " ");**bold**  
will do the work. It will convert all the white space to single whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very complex regex..simplify the regex and that would definitely increasre the performance

Use `\s+` and replace it with a single space